# I want pushed object touches pushed object, how can i do that?

Tags: arrays, object, push

```
var bullets = {
    speed: 8,
    array: []
}
var zombie = {
    speed: 1,
    array: []
}
// when bullet touches the zombie
if(zomb.x > bullets.array.x && zomb.x < bullets.array.x && zomb.y > bullets.array.y && zomb.y < bullets.array.y) {
    alert()
}
```

I was making a shooting game, i dont know how can 2 pushed object collides each other.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to detect collision.

Remember that object size is required in addition to coordinates, for any algorithm.

I suggest a simple example as follows.

```
squaredDistance = Math.pow(zomb.x - bullet.x, 2) + Math.pow(zomb.y - bullet.y, 2)
if (squaredDistance < threshold) {
    alert("hit!")
}
```

In this code, threshold depends on objects' size.